# What can be the error in this float calculation?

Tags: variables, vim, floating-point, numbers

I always have a lot of troubles with variables: float, string and numbers.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?
What did I wrong?

```
 let beforeE = '2.18' 
 let nrzeros = '000' 
 let newnr = beforeE * 1.nrzeros 
 echo newnr
```

This gives as output 2000 and not 2180.
Why?
I tried to change variables with str2float and tried a few other things
but I receive only errors:
Using float as a string or Variable type mismatch

Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let beforeE = 2.18 " or str2float('2.18')
let nrzeros = '000'
let newnr = beforeE * str2float(1.nrzeros)
echo newnr
```

Comment: Ah.. I had to remove the quotes around 2.18 :) But the result is 2180.0 and not 2180, how can I have the results without the ".0" or better remove the ".0" if there are only zeros after the "."?

Comment: Is something like `echo a==floor(newnr) ? float2nr(newnr) : newnr` what you are looking for?